joining with variable delimiters in google sheets using query()
I am looking for an efficient way to join with variable delimiters as in the output below where there is a variable number of "~" used as delimiters perhaps as a lamda() and query()
for example, the table below combines A3:F3 with variable tildas ~ using
="~"&A3&"~~~"&B3&"~"&C3&"~~~"&D3&"~"&E3&"~~"&F3&"~"

Join() actually wont work well because it also wont add encasing ~, textjoin() can be used in lamda() to combine with arrayformula().
But, I may want to combine this function with a query() or other formulas and found it is difficult to insert strings into a query and needs a workaround to accomplish concatentation of columns
=transpose(query(transpose(_you query_);;COLUMNS(_you query_)))

something simple like =QUERY(A1:B4, "Select A & 'two' ") fails.



ID
First
Last
Birthday
Siblings
Age
Output




AB
Jack
Messi
01/01/19
Maria, Mary
5
~AB~~~Jack~Messi~~~01/01/19~Maria, Mary~~5~


CD
Jack
Smith
01/02/19

5
~CD~~~Jack~Smith~~~01/02/19~~~5~


EF
Sam
Messi
02/01/19
Tara, James, Billy
5
~EF~~~Sam~Messi~~~02/01/19~Tara, James, Billy~~5~


GH
Samatha
Reynoldo
03/02/19
Andrea
5
~GH~~~Samatha~Reynoldo~~~03/02/19~Andrea~~5~


IJ
John
Jordan
04/01/19

5
~IJ~~~John~Jordan~~~04/01/19~~~5~


KL
Jamie
Bryant
05/02/18
Jack, Michael, Elizabeth
5
~KL~~~Jamie~Bryant~~~05/02/18~Jack, Michael, Elizabeth~~5~


MN
Janie
Oneil
01/01/17

7
~MN~~~Janie~Oneil~~~01/01/17~~~7~




There's no way to do this with QUERY.
You can define a custom function F(arr,ins) from Data > Named functions:
F(arr,ins) ← ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(REDUCE(arr,TOCOL(SPLIT(ins,"()")),LAMBDA(a,c,LET(
                s,SPLIT(c,","),i,CHOOSECOLS(s,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(s)-1)),t,CHOOSECOLS(s,-1),
                REDUCE(a,i,LAMBDA(a_,i_,IF(i_=0,{IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),t),IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(a)-1),)},)&
                TO_TEXT(a_)&IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(a))=i_,t,)))))),LAMBDA(r,JOIN(,r))))

And use it as follows:
=F(A2:F8,"(1,3,~~~)(0,2,4,6,~)(5,~~)")


Which means: insert ~~~ after columns 1 and 3, insert ~ before column 1 and after columns 2, 4, 6, insert ~~ after column 5.
You can also define the function directly within the formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   F,LAMBDA(arr,ins,BYROW(REDUCE(arr,TOCOL(SPLIT(ins,"()")),LAMBDA(a,c,LET(
       s,SPLIT(c,","),i,CHOOSECOLS(s,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(s)-1)),t,CHOOSECOLS(s,-1),
       REDUCE(a,i,LAMBDA(a_,i_,IF(i_=0,{IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),t),IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(a)-1),)},)&
         TO_TEXT(a_)&IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(a))=i_,t,)))))),LAMBDA(r,JOIN(,r)))),
   F(A2:F8,"(1,3,~~~)(0,2,4,6,~)(5,~~)")))


